# How to generally utilize linux commands on Mac OSX without needing an entire Linux system running?

Tags: linux, macos

I am currently using the `mt` command in Linux to control and manipulate tape drives. I am wondering if there is a way I can use the `mt` command without having to first boot into Linux or have a virtual machine. In other words, is there something like a lightweight minimal wrapper that would allow me to use the `mt` command in Mac OSX. Ideally I would like to put this into a Mac OSX app. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Install compiler. 2. Download `mt` sources. 3. Compile and install. There is no need for any wrapper, just compile the program.

Comment: Or go check [`homebrew`](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: @KamilCuk I am a bit unfamiliar with compiling in Mac OSX. What compiler would I use and how would I know compatibility? Where could I find these sources? Thanks!

Comment: If I wanted to write my own program on Mac OSX via xcode, what would the biggest hurdle be? Would it be getting the system to recognize something like the `/dev/st0` system for scsi?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380390/is-it-possible-to-install-the-gnu-mt-tape-drive-command-in-osx